# Node Js Angular 6 adding trailing slash to urls error (adding on external urls as well)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, http

I have an Angular 6 App and in my **server.ts** I have added logic to add trailing slash on all internal route urls like this

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {


  if (req.path.endsWith('/') && req.path.length > 1) {
      next();
  } else if (req.path.indexOf('?') > -1) {
    const start = req.path.indexOf('?');
    res.redirect(301, req.path.slice(0, start) + '/' + req.path.slice(start , req.path.length));
  }
  else {
    res.redirect(301, req.path + '/');
  }
});
```

It adds trailing slash to the urls but the issue is that it is adding on all urls(internal and external) like these

```
/main.eb7e5105c175d9740e4e.js/

/styles.2364125a82ccf2f40c44.css/
```

and thus page is not loading correctly , I just want to add trailing slashes to the urls which are in **app-routing.module.ts**